# Packing map<string, string> type into google.protobuf.Any

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-java, protobuf-java

I'm struggling with packing a protobuf `map` type into `google.protobuf.Any` in Java. The proto message I'm working with has the following schema:

```
message Msg {
  google.protobuf.Any value = 1;
}
```

For example, to pack a `StringValue` into `Any`, I can simply construct a `StringValue` and use `Any.pack`:

```
Msg.newBuilder().setValue(Any.pack(StringValue.of("value"))).build()
```

I can do the same with all the other protobuf types since their respective message representations are available in the library, such as `Int32Value`, `DoubleValue`, `ListValue`, and so on.

However, I'd like to pack a protobuf `map` type into `google.protobuf.Any`, but the challenge here is that `protobuf-java` library does not provide `Message` representation for maps. Do you have any suggestions or ideas on how to do that?

Comment: You can only pack Messages and map is a field type not a message. StringValue is a message wrapper for string (scalar) types (permitting e.g. null value). You need to create a wrapping Message type that has a field that corresponds to your `map` type and then `pack` that containing message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Map` has the parameters `<string, string>`, so there can't be a pre-made wrapper.

But you can make a wrapper yourself, just like the others in `wrappers.proto` you are familiar with:

```protobuf
message MapStringStringValue {
  map<string, string> value = 1;
}
```